# 'Simple 220V' relay with a 36W LED Par light

Tags: power, relay, safety

I have the relay below, it has 3-7 input voltage needed for the control signal, I'm using a STM32F103C8T6 which is 3.3V and it is able to control the relay successfully.

For testing:
- The top left connector is connected to 3.3V (from the same STM32 via the horizontal breadboard + line)
- The bottom left connector is connected to a small LED, and 470 ohm resistor.

This works fine (including the rest of the setup).

However, before replacing the left connectors to a 220V (European power) and a 36W (max) LED Power light device, is there anything I should take into account?
Since I want to build it first in an enclosure to make sure I cannot touch the 220V connector directly, I would like to have a double check to see if I missed something.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe including a Fuse to protect against any unwanted short-circuit, alongside protections for the transistor turn-off and turn-on, like reducing any dv/dt in the transistor( I suppose you´re switchig your relay with a transistor) and the back emf protection diode in parallel with the coil to protect turn-off. As it´s a LED device then I assume the product has its protections included in the circuit.
As you´ve stated it´s working fine, I don´t see there would be any problems with your circuit.

Comment: Thank you very much ... I don't use a transistor, but the transistor is part of the relay I'm using (you cannot see it, but it's on the right of the picture, but blurred).

Comment: You´re welcome! I think there could be some more things but these are a few of the most importants to extend circuit´s life.

Comment: I ordered fuses and holders ... I need to check if a protection diode is there (I think it's also part of the relay module). And the LED device I assume has indeed its own protection. Even than, the relais module has an optical isolator.

Comment: That´s great. It looks it´s gonna work fine then.